# How to remove products url for specific Category URL-REWRITE

Tags: magento2, products, url-rewrite

I want to remove url of prodcuts for a specific category. How can i remove specific category URL-REWRITE? using Query pro-grammatically

Comment: Did you resolve your query?

Comment: yes i done that let me past my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


  $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('url_rewrite');
    try {
        $sql = "DELETE  FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` LIKE 'category' AND `target_path` LIKE '%id/234'";
        $connection->query($sql);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
```

here in querry target_path (%id/234) defines your category

Comment: Good to know that you have resolved it. +1 :)

Comment: thanks for your help man

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to delete product URL for specific category

```
DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE target_path LIKE 'catalog/product/view/id/[PROD_ID]/category/[CAT_ID]'
```

where `PROD_ID` is your product id, and `CAT_ID` is the ID of category from which you need to delete URL.